Plotting an RSSI heatmap with seaborn
I'm trying to plot an interpolated heatmap of RSSI (received signal strength indication) point values on a static map with Python and Seaborn.
The data is in a local InfluxDB but for the sake of this question, I exported them as CSV. The CSV file and the additionally used shape file are available here: https://cloud.gofferje.net/s/BT7bJaS7ybtP8zn
This is my code:
import requests as r
import io
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
import seaborn as sns
import tilemapbase as tm

df=pd.read_csv('rangemap.csv')
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, 
    geometry = gpd.points_from_xy(df['lon'], df['lat']), 
    crs = 'EPSG:4326')
gdf = gdf.to_crs("EPSG:3857")

vlk = gpd.read_file("Valkeakoski.shp")
vlk = vlk.to_crs("EPSG:3857")

tm.init(create=True)
extent = tm.extent_from_frame(vlk)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,10),layout="constrained")
ax.xaxis.set_visible(False)
ax.yaxis.set_visible(False)
plotter = tm.Plotter(extent, tm.tiles.build_OSM(), width=1000)
plotter.plot(ax)
sns.kdeplot(data=gdf,x=gdf['geometry'].x,y=gdf['geometry'].y,fill=True,cmap='turbo',alpha=0.3,levels=20,weights=gdf['rssi'],cbar=True,ax=ax,zorder=3)
vlk.plot(color=(1,1,1,0),edgecolor="black",linewidth=0.5,ax=ax)

So far, I have achieved a plot which looks about right:

What is confusing me a bit are the values in the color bar. The RSSI values in the CSV file go from -55 to -145. What I would like to see in the color bar are the actual RSSI values. I assume what the color bar is showing are the results of the KDE math based on the RSSI as weights?
I also tried to use hue=gdf['rssi'] instead of weights=gdf['rssi'] but that doesn't create a map at all, however, the color bar looks right...

How would I get an interpolated map of the RSSI values with the "right" color bar, i.e. the color bar showing the RSSI values?

Instead of sns.kdeplot(...) you probably want to try something like ax.tricontourf(gdf['geometry'].x, gdf['geometry'].y, gdf['rssi'], levels=np.arange(-120, -54, 5), alpha=0.3, cmap='turbo').

I didn't know that yet, thanks! I tried it but it doesn't seem to interpolate. The problem is that there's some "islands" in my data from where I have measuring point but no measuring points from areas in between. In the tricontourf plot it kinda looks like they would have their own base station. Also, I have a few outliers, probably caused by false GPS reports which totally mess up the tricontourf plot. At least those I would have to somehow filter out but I don't know how.

kdeplot works very different from what you want to achieve.  Without weights, each x,y gets a mini Gaussian bump. All these bumps are summed together to obtain the kde. When also working with weights, each of the little gaussian is scaled with these weights.  Using the RSSI as weights is very different from calculating intermediate RSSI values. You really need to work with the contour functions, not the kdes.

(Note that weights are supposed to be positive. If all weights are negative, they get scaled by the sum of all weights, converting them back to positive. With mixed positive and negative weights, it gets very messy. As such, your lowest RSSI values get weighted heavier than the highest.)

I see. Is there a way to smooth the tricontour plot? The plot looks pretty wild, I assume because the measuring points aren't distributed evenly... See https://cloud.gofferje.net/s/sZaMoDYP5H2bMkx

See e.g. Smooth Contourf plot completely filled for some ideas to work with ax.contourf() and interpolate the data via different functions.  ax.tricontourf() only does linear interpolation, which is most "true" to the data given, but looks jagged. See also griddata()  with method='cubic'.
